# Connecting two PCBs with different headers

Tags: pcb, connector, header

I would like to connect these 2 boards together. Left one has male header, right one female. Ground and 3V3 supply are not pin-to-pin aligned, while all other pins are. What would be the best way to connect these two boards together (besides nasty individual jumper wires or custom PCB between these two)?

[image: Picture 1]

Answer (score 1):

Create a wiring harness using the proper mating connectors for each side.  You can then route any pin on the first connector to any pin on the second connector.

Here are some connectors that would probably work...

XG5M-5035-N, 25 pin x 2 row, 0.1" pitch, female, $5.83 on Digikey
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/XG5M-5035-N/Z5274-ND/2627561

http://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-icdw.pdf

Comment: This is definitely the route I'd take. It's the cheapest and easiest to control

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would add this header to the male connector only for the matching pins and not for your 3.3V volts supply and ground pins.  Then, you could use those nasty jumpers for 3.3V and ground pins.  This would elevate your connections and allow you to have some room to wire power and ground accordingly.

[image]

Comment: OK, but what after you add this header to the male connector?

Comment: I mean, how do you connect both boards after adding this header in the picture?

Comment: Put the jumpers to their respective places.  and simply mount the female connector (with the added header) to the male connector.  Those jumpers might need to be soldered last to cut the distance of the wire as short as possible.  That's my proposition.  I am sure other people would do it differently.